# App crashes when trying to take a picture on different devices - Android

Tags: android, camera, image, android-camera, android-camera-intent

My app has enables the users to take a photo using the camera.

I've tested it on several devices(Nexus S,Nexus One, HTC Magic and Galaxy S). The app worked fine on the first 3 phones, but crashed with the Galaxy.

This is the code I wrote -

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "121.jpg");
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image capture by camera");


imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);
```

And this is the OnActivityResult function -

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                else if (requestCode == 2)
                {
                    sun=getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
                    File f = new File(sun);
                    thePic.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(f));
                    }

        }
}
```

The resultCode is returned as 0(not RESULT_OK), and then the app crahses.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the logcat output. That will simplify finding why it's crashing. Mi first guess it would be related to the fact that the SGS has two cameras.

Comment: Please keep in mind that changing the Camera parameters in any part of your code might originate issues in some devices. In any case, the logcat output will surely else in figuring out what is going wrong.